# Spring repository: find by a field with two conditions

Tags: java, spring

I want to find all Users with name like `?1%` which are not in a passed in list `?2`:

I use this method name: `findByNameStartingWithAndNotIn` but I get this error:

`No property notIn found for type User!`

Does it mean that I have to write my own custom SQL?

Comment: What is the body of the `findByNameStartingWithAndNotIn` method?

Comment: @Nikolas - no body I guess, just the interface

Comment: there's no body for it, I'm trying to use spring supported keywords inside method names: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: What do you mean *not in a list*? is the list from a `join`?

Comment: I updated the question (the list of users is passed in as an argument)

Comment: Could you try `findByNameStartingWithAndNameNotIn`  ?

Comment: does NameNotIn mean that I have to pass in list of names?

Comment: Which property does the list reference? You need to I include the name of the property as well something like `<property>NotIn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring data does not know that you want to use `Name` for the second clause too.

Just specify it separately, try:

`List<User> findByNameStartingWithAndNameNotIn(String prefix, List<String> namesToExclude)`